# Could not find or load main class Javac

Tags: java, selenium

Quick note, I went through every single other question through here and nothing seems to work.

So, here is my issue. All I want to do is create a windows batch script that will be used to execute my selenium project on Jenkins. Sounds simple right ? Its probably is, but I am missing something...

Here is my project https://github.com/Daviditooe/Nomad

First command I tried:

```
javac src/nomad/execute/Execute.java 

Execute.java:9: error: package nomad.sites does not exist                                                               import nomad.sites.MmaShare;
```

It also couldnt find any of the jars, so I add all of them

Then I tried:

```
javac -cp Jars\* src\nomad\execute\Execute.java
```

This fixed the jars issue but the package not found still exists

So then I tried compiling every single package at the same time

```
javac -cp Jars\* src\nomad\execute\*.java src\nomad\actions\*.java src\nomad\baseactions\*.java src\nomad\browsers\Chrome.java src\nomad\directory\*.java src\nomad\scripts\*.java src\nomad\sites\*.java src\nomad\urltools\*.java
```

So, now its not crashing, then I tried compiling...

```
java src\nomad\execute\Execute
```

And its giving me Could not find or load main class

So That last thing I tried was compile all of them at the same time.

```
java src\nomad\actions\MmaShareActions src\nomad\baseactions\BaseActions src\nomad\browsers\Chrome src\nomad\directory\Directory src\nomad\execute\Execute src\nomad\scripts\Vpn src\nomad\sites\MmaShare src\nomad\urltools\UrlTools
```

Still no luck... anything thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you go through anything on how to compile Java from the command line?

Comment: You need to go into the src folder and then call ```javac nomad/execute/Execute.java```

Comment: Sorry, I just updated everything I tried until this last min. Yes @Stefan I tried but its seem to be an Environment setup problem... ?

Comment: @DaveNewton yes sir I did, The strange thing is I have done it before without any issues. its simple formula normally. Javac /path to file/Execute.java. Then java /path to file/Execute

Comment: You must go into the src folder, not provides it as an argument! The ```java``` command does not compile anything, it executes a class. Java expects a class name with package like: java nomad.execute.Execute

Comment: Hi @Stefan thanks for the feed back, Im not sure what you mean. This is the exact command I used javac nomad/execute/Execute.java, Then java nomad/execute/Execute

Comment: @Stefan unfortunately its still giving me the same error...

Comment: What @Stefan suggested is correct make sure that the file name and the class name in your code are exactly the same

Comment: hi @RVISHAL, yes they are. Execute.class and Execute.java

Comment: The error could not load main class means 2 things. Either your execute class has no main method (mostly not) or the class name declared in your source file is different from the class file name produced by javac. If your class file name is Execute.class then inside your source code it should begin like class Execute{}

Comment: well, the thing is. I am not getting that error when i just execute 'javac nomad\execute\Execute.java', when I execute that it gives me jar and packages missing. When I execute javac -cp Jars\* + building all java files in the directory. It works but then when I compile the Execute.class file it doesnt..... I hope that makes sense.....

Comment: Your problem description is very incomplete. You should publish the whole project somewhere together with the command that you entered and the output that you got.

Comment: Hey @Stefan he is the project and the commands I am using https://github.com/Daviditooe/Nomad  `javac -cp Jars\* nomad\execute\*.java nomad\actions\*.java nomad\baseactions\*.java nomad\browsers\Chrome.java nomad\directory\*.java nomad\scripts\*.java nomad\sites\*.java nomad\urltools\*.java` then I execute the .class file `java nomad\execute\Execute`

Answer (score 0):

Again: You must go into the src folder before you execute javac and java!

I can compile and execute it on my Linux Laptop:

```
stefan@stefanpc:/hdd/stefan/Downloads/Nomad-master/src$ javac -cp '../Jars/*' nomad/execute/*.java nomad/actions/*.java nomad/baseactions/*.java nomad/browsers/Chrome.java nomad/directory/*.java nomad/scripts/*.java nomad/sites/*.java nomad/urltools/*.java
Note: nomad/baseactions/BaseActions.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

```
stefan@stefanpc:/hdd/stefan/Downloads/Nomad-master/src$ java -cp '../Jars/*:.' nomad.execute.Execute
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /hdd/stefan/Downloads/Nomad-master/src/C:\Users\Davidito\Desktop\AutoLinks\Jars\chromedriver.exe
```

Of course my Linux machine does not have the chromedriver.exe installed.

Under Windows, you must use "\" instead of "/" and you must use ";" instead of ":". Note that you must add the current folder "." to the class path when you execute the program. Otherwise java would only search in the Jars folder.

Comment: wow, I cant believe I let that slip by me! Thank you @stefan this solved my problem!